# onclick function on a html template (shadow dom)

Tags: html, css, onclick, shadow-dom

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
            <section class="progress-area"></section>
            <section class="uploaded-area"></section>
`

class writePostModal extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();
        // Create a shadow root
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

        progressArea = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".progress-area"),
        uploadedArea = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".uploaded-area");
        
        uploadedArea.classList.add("onprogress");
        progressArea.innerHTML = progressHTML;
        if (loaded == total) {
            progressArea.innerHTML = "";
            let uploadedHTML = `<li class="row" file="${name}">
                                <div class="content upload">
                                  <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                                  <div class="details">
                                    <span class="name">${name} • Uploaded</span>
                                    <span class="size">${fileSize}</span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" id="icon-size" file="${name}" onclick="removeFile('${name}')"></i>
                                </li>`;
                uploadedArea.classList.remove("onprogress");
                uploadedArea.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", uploadedHTML); //remove this line if you don't want to show upload history
              }
            });
                    
        }
        
        
    }
    removeFile(name) {
        const deleteFile = uploadedArea.querySelector(`li[file="${name}"]`);
        console.log(deleteFile);
        deleteFile.remove();
    }

}
```

This is a simplified version of my code, but the error still exists in this line :

```
 <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" 
id="icon-size" file="${name}" 
onclick="removeFile('${name}')"></i>
```

Error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: removeFile is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick
```

I am pretty sure the error is the i tag could not find the functions, which I already declared in the constructor. I tested this function in html,css,js and it works just fine.

How to define the onclick attribute in the html tag? I really need the event listener to be in the tag instead of manipulating the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick="removeFile('${name}')"` will call a **GLOBAL** `removeFile` function

If you want to execute a **method** on an encompassing Web Component,

You need to do ***something like*:**

`onclick="this.getRootNode().host.removeFile('${name}')"`